# Java vaadin table fields customization

Tags: java, styles, vaadin

I have the following properties to display in the Vaadin Table

```
public class Item
{
String itemName;
String itemSource;
String itemStatus;
...
}
```

Next, I retrieve my data using the ItemContainer, and connect it to the table:

```
ItemContainer container = new ItemContainer(Item.class, app);
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

The table will display the data based on Item class. 
The question: can I change "somehow" the datatype of the fields on the "fly" ? So I want change the "itemStatus" to be Label since display HTML tags in correct styles.

For example the text in "itemStatus" is: `<b>Status is:</b><i>Completed</i>`. I want to see in the table formatted string **Status is:***Completed*

Answer (score 1):

You can override a container property in `Table` by adding a generated column with the same id:

```
tablet.addGeneratedColumn("itemStatus", new ColumnGenerator() {
    @Override
    public Object generateCell(Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId) {
        Label label = new Label("" + source.getContainerProperty(itemId, columnId).getValue());
        label.setContentMode(ContentMode.HTML);
        label.setSizeUndefined();
        return label;
    }
});
```